# Write file: Data consistency in practice

Tags: caching, storage, consistency, acid

I am working on a multi-user file storage system, in the real world
this system must face up to the event of system crash or power
failure, so I'm researching for Consistency and Durability.

Many of database systems supported ACID, and modern computer systems
supported journaling file system. I have noticed that a logging system
will be very important for such systems, with a logging system we can
figure out what happened and what has not happened before the crash,
so while system restarting we could do a befitting recovery job.

A typical logging system working steps:

1. write log (data or just meta-data)
2. write actual data
3. commit that log

So when system crash event happens there are only a few possibilities:

1. log is not complete: so just ignore it
2. log is not committed: so data is not complete - do rollback
3. log is committed: the operation is finished

Some journaling file systems work like that.

I have no idea about how a database system works, in general a
database system is a software running in userspace, and as I know,
there are several things between file writing function and disk
surface:

1. process cache
2. system cache
3. on-disk cache

So when function returns, the data may be not on the disk, it may be
in these caches.

On Windows Systems caching can be disabled by FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING
flag when CreateFile, MSDN said "When caching is disabled, all read
and write operations directly access the physical disk", my first
question is, does FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING turns off on-disk cache as
well ? or how can I make sure the data has reached the surface of disk
?

And a further question: SATA and SCSI disks are using "command
queuing" technology, the commands in the queue could be re-ordered to
be processed more efficiently, but a logging system depends on the
time-order, is command queuing bad for logging systems(in userspace) ?
or how can I make sure A has been written before B ?

Comment: Q1: The FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH flag turns off system cache, data will be cached in on-disk cache but still written to disk. FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING eliminates all read-ahead file buffering and disk caching as well. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/99794/ Q2: It doesn't matter any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic way to overwrite data in a crash-safe way is:

1. Write the data to a *new* storage location first.  (You're not actually overwriting anything yet.)
2. Tell the OS to flush the above to stable storage, using something like the POSIX `fsync` function.  This is meant to flush caches and everything, so that when the function returns, the data is actually physically on disk.
3. Write a "journal" entry somewhere that indicates that all the new data for this update has been written and is ready to commit.
4. Flush the journal entry to disk.
5. Read the data that you wrote in step 1 and write it to the "real" storage location.  (This is where you do the actual overwrite.)
6. Write another journal entry that says the change has been committed.
7. Delete the temporary file that you created in step 1.

The flushes serve as [write barriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_barrier): they ensure that everything before the flush has been safely stored on disk before anything after the flush can be written.  *Between* a pair of barriers, reordering of writes (e.g. due to disks with command queueing) isn't a problem, because the barriers ensure that the order is correct in the places where it matters.  In step 1, you don't care if the disk physically writes the second half of the file before it writes the first half; you just care that the whole file has been written before the journal entry attesting that the new file is complete.

After a crash, you go through the journal and process each entry:

- If you find a file from step 1 that doesn't have a corresponding entry from step 3, treat the file as incomplete and discard it.  This is a rollback of an incomplete change.
- If the entry from step 3 is present but not the one from step 6, repeat step 5.  It's possible that step 5 was partially completed before the crash, but that doesn't matter; it just means you might be overwriting some of the data with identical bytes, which is harmless.
- If the entry from step 6 is present, repeat step 7 by deleting the file if it still exists.

---

You might find it informative to read [PostgreSQL's documentation on reliability and write-ahead logging](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/wal.html) (which is PostgreSQL's term for the sort of journaling mechanism described above.)  It incorporates additional safety measures, such as checksumming of WAL (journal) entries to protect against corruption, and disk flushes are deferred and batched for better performance during normal operation (at the expense of crash recovery possibly taking a little longer).

Speaking of databases, however, it'd probably be much easier and safer to actually *use* one — with its robust and well-tested consistency and durability mechanisms — than trying to roll your own.  If a full database server like PostgreSQL is too heavyweight for your application, consider using something lighter like [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) or [Berkeley DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/berkeleydb/overview/index.html) (which is a low-level key-value store, not an SQL relational database).  [Both](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/db-faq-095848.html#DoesBerkeleyDBsupporttransactions) support [atomic commits](https://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html).

Comment: Yes, SQL things are too heavyweight. I have read the documents of Berkeley DB and UnQLite on transaction, for Isolation, only one write-operation are allowed at a given time, this is not very suitable for our project, we need transactions run concurrently, and every transaction is a batch of files - all or nothing. So I am still searching and learning.